# Creating object with request.user producing unpredictable results

Tags: django

I have a model with a ForeignKey to User called `ActivityEntryItem`. A class called `Logger` provides a simplified interface for creating these models. Here are some excerpts from `Logger`:

```
def __init__(self, organization=None, user=None):
    result = super(Logger,self).__init__()
    if user:
        self.user = user
    if organization:
        self.organization = organization
    return result

def log(self, **kwargs):
    # Snip for the sake of brevity
    kwargs_subset['user'] = self.user
    entry = ActivityLogEntry.objects.create(**kwargs_subset)
```

`user` is passed into `__init__` as `request.user` from a view using `Logger`.

It seemed that everything was working fine. Then, I registered as a new user in the application and, after setting a password and authenticating, I triggered this code as the recently registered user. The `ActivityEntryItem` object that resulted in this case points to the user I was previously logged in as rather than the one I was logged in as at the time the code was triggered.

Every time I repeat this process (i.e., inviting a new user, registering as that invited user, triggering the code), the user that's referenced by the newly created ActivityLogEntry points to the last user that was logged in rather than the user that's actually logged in.

I suspected this had something to do with request.user being a `SimpleLazyObject` prior to it being evaluated. So, I changed `__init__` so call `self.user.pk` after `self.user = user`. This seems to have fixed the problem. I also noticed that restarting the server makes this problem go away.

I suspect this is a bug in Django (1.4), but I wanted to check in here first to see if anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening. Thanks.

**Edit:** This mixin is used in a view where logging needs to happen. This shows how the logger is instantiated, and how it eventually logs.

```
class LoggerMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger = Logger(user=request.user)
        return super(LoggerMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am 100% certain this is *not* a bug in Django. Rather, it is in the code that calls your Logger class. Where/how is it instantiated?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I updated my post with the code you requested. As far as instantiation is concerned, there isn't much that you'll find terribly interesting. Also, don't you find it suspicious that simply accessing self.user.pk eliminates the issue?

Comment: So, this mixin is being used as part of a class-based view? Can you show an example of the main class and the URLconf? The designers of class-based views went to some trouble to ensure that nothing was persisted between requests, which looks like what is happening to you, so I suspect something wrong in how you've set it up. It might also be useful to see what middleware you have.